# How to get a List of domain names that are available for purchase

Tags: c#, dns

I want to build a website that will display a list of domain names that are available for purchase with .com extension.

i found this code (using System.DirectoryServices):

```
  using (var forest = Forest.GetCurrentForest())
            {
                foreach (Domain domain in forest.Domains)
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
```

but it displays only my domains.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to enumerate domain names in the public DNS system.

A DNS domain name is distinct from an "NT Domain" or "Active Directory Domain" which is a different concept entirely. `System.DirectoryServices` is the LDAP client in the .NET Framework and has nothing to do with DNS.

The DNS client in .NET: `System.Net.Dns` features resolution commands, but it cannot tell you if a public DNS domain name is registered or available - because it is possible to register a domain name and then never create a DNS Zone File for it - so the name itself will not resolve, even though it is registered.

Public domain name availability is discoverable typically using WHOIS or some other purpose-built API provided by the controller of the top-level domain you seek to query.